# How to tile two program windows in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, tile

I want to tile two windows programs horizontally in C#. It's for a data view program using Chrome for viewing 2d images and Unity3d is for 3d and navigation.

For example, i can select two programs in windows task manager, and the context has an option to tile them.

Is there a handle in the .Net framework for tiling different program windows?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing is to use MoveWindow (Where hWnd is the window to move):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

MoveWindow(ApplicationHandle, 600, 600, 600, 600, true);
```

If you don't know the window pointer, you can use the FindWindow functionality.

Also worth a read is MSDN SetWindowPos (Very similar to MoveWindow).